# What does "I can't have brass cutting me favors in public" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In Brick (2005), Brendan, student , talking to his principal, Trueman.

> Brendan: All right, I need you off my back completely for  the next few weeks.There might be some heat soon.
>
> Trueman: If it's something I can't cover, I won't go to bat for you.
>
> Brendan: If I get caught like that, it's curtains anyway. **I can't have brass cutting me favors in public**.

My understanding of Brendan's words: Brendan misses Brass to be asked for his favors in public.

Is my understanding is right or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Brass*  is not a proper noun. That is why it was not capitalized in the text.

> [brass](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brass)
>   5. Informal.
>   a. high-ranking military officers.
>   b. any very important officials.
>   (Dictionary.com)

Here, *brass* refers to the administration, specifically Trueman.

*Cutting me favors* is synonymous with *doing me favors*. In other words, Brendan can't have the vice principal doing any favors for Brendan in public.

Comment: Thank You for correcting me, But how to understand "**can't have**" here? Is Brendan missing the principle here?

Comment: No. Brendan will not allow or accept Trueman to do any favors. Also, it's spelled [princi**pal**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/principal). Principle is something else.

Comment: @DhanrajKumar _**"Can't have"**_ is a _contraction_ of _**cannot have**_. It is one of the scores of idiomatic uses of the verb _have_. Here, _"can't (cannot) have"_ means _"can not tolerate"_.